# Python flask not displaying HTML file

Tags: python, html, json, flask, response

I am using a JSON file that consists of various job details. This JSON file is in my repository so I am using
`response = requests.get('https://github.com/myname/Beatiful-Soup/blob/main/jsonFile.json')` I have to convert this response to JSON file in order to display these job details on my HTML file. I set up the flask environment and everything but by some reason my HTML file not displaying any information. How could I fix that?

below is my Python, and HTML

```
import json
import requests
from flask import Flask, render_template

# write a code to give call to json file and then render
# html page
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def displayJobDetails():

    response = requests.get('https://github.com/myName/Beatiful-Soup/blob/main/jsonFile.json')
    data = json.loads(response.text);
    return render_template('index.html', message="data")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug=True)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Display the Job Details</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <p> {{ message }}} </p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

my webpage displays only {{message}}

Answer (score 1):

You are setting message to a string, not your actual data. Try this:

```
return render_template('index.html', message=data)
```